# listening to communication between a local application and a device

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I have a windows application on my PC which connects to a device over telnet. It sends a series of commands to the device, and the device responds to it.

Is there any way I can listen to what that program is writing to the device?

I tried using win32 socket programming to create a client that connects to the application. But, I get an error saying connection refused. When I analyze the traffic between the application and device on wireshark, I can see that the application uses different ports each time it reads from or writes to the telnet port(23) of the device.

Is there any way I can read the commands sent by the program to the device?

Comment: You should see the commands in wireshark if you "follow tcp stream". The client's port is just a random one, assigned by the system because the application doesn't care about source port.

Comment: I can see the commands in wireshark. But i need to replicate those same commands and over a different interface to another device at runtime. I do not have access to the source code of that application which sends those commands.

Comment: "Replicate those same commands" as in "copy exactly the same stream of commands to another device", or as in "reverse-engineer the format and parameters of commands to be able to send your own commands at any time"? There can be an answer in both cases, but they're different.

Comment: do your client abort during the TCP connect phase or after the connection is established?

Comment: @Anton: I want to replicate exactly the same commands

Comment: @Davide: It aborts during the connect phase

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture program's output to the device
programmatically, the right way is not to connect to the program (you
can't tap into an existing connection), but instead provide a *server*
that will stand for target device from the program's point of view.

It's going to work if the program can be configured to connect to the
device at different address and port. Write a "proxy" that listens on
some fixed port, and for any accepted connection, opens a *client*
connection to the *real* device. Then it should forward data in both
directions between the accepted connection from the program and the
client connection to the device. During this, you can also parse data
or do whatever you want with them, e.g. forward them to *yet another*
connection to another real device.